# List.get(0) working fine in expressions window of eclipse but when I run my code it throws classcasteexception

Tags: java, eclipse, classcastexception, rest-assured

I am getting response from restassured post method and I store response in Arraylist. When I try to use the value stored in Arraylist like list.get(0) it throws class caste exception but In expression window I can see value stored in arraylist.

1> I checked the type which is returned by rest assured , it returns arraylist.

2> I tried using hash map but no luck

```
List<String> list = 
             ResponseHolder.response.then().extract().path("data");
//On below line exception is thrown
String a = list.get(0).toString();
```

refer screenshot for better understanding..
[image]

Comment: I am not sure what is the issue behind but ur trying to assign the json object to list which is wrong and you are getting the value from List string and you don't need to call tostring() method on string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ResponseHolder.response.then().extract().path("data");` may not return `List` of `String`

use wildcard `?`

```java
List<?> list = 
             ResponseHolder.response.then().extract().path("data");
//On below line exception is thrown
String a = list.get(0).toString();
```